# Are there any up to date walk though videos on how to use Tellor for fetching data feeds? or use how to use Tellor in general?

Tags: oracles, tellor

Most of the videos on YouTube are out of date and the code doesn't match with what is on GitHub, making it really frustrating to follow along and learn how to use Tellor. The project is really cool but as a newbie trying to figure out how to actually use the protocol is kind of difficult. The resources online are limited or out of date across the board. I assume their documents and code are constantly being updated, which is great, but for the average developer trying to get use to working with this oracle, it makes it very hard to stay motivated and continue to use this them or follow along with the videos online. At the very least I would love for the 'sample using Tellor' or the 'playground' code to be in sync with the videos online.

Comment: Well, you found a good opportunity, create the videos yourself. Even the project may encourage you to do the videos.

Answer (score 1):

Ask and you shall receive! Thanks for bringing this to our attention!

See video for updated Sample Using Tellor exercise:

https://youtu.be/GUTVhtffQQs